# How to change UILabel size as per text with limited width

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview

Currently my label is having width of 100 pixels by default.

*the text on label varies dynamically*

my requirement is that

**The label size should change as per text and its width should limited to 300 pixels.**

**After 300 pixels the text goes to next line and the height of the label has to be increses.**

how to achieve this scenario..

self.messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

```
self.messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20);

self.messageLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.messageLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];

messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
messageLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

[self.view addSubview:messageLabel];
```

*to get the text size :*

***`CGSize labelSize = [self.messageLabel.text sizeWithFont:self.messageLabel.font];`***

And i can able to *Change the width of label as per text*

***`self.messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width-10, 20);`***

But how to move the text to next line after every 300 pixels and

label size increase in height as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-(CGSize)getLabelSize:(NSString *)text
{

   UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(300.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
return labelSize;



}
```

Use this method.
I hope it helps you.